# Text extraction not applying

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

Working on storm crawler 1.13 and elastic search 6.5.2. In text extraction I am applying **MAIN** tag which maintains the main content of my web-page. Unfortunately, When I add only **MAIN** its grabbing whole web-page content which includes headers.

**Not Worked Properly:**

```
 textextractor.include.pattern:
  - MAIN[role="main"]
```

But If I add additional tags under **MAIN** its grabbing actual content what I expected.

Worked:

```
  textextractor.include.pattern:
   - MAIN[role="main"]
   - DIV[id="content--primary"]
   - DIV[id="content--secondary"]
```

Any solution for this, if I want to get all content between **MAIN** tags. I have lot of sites in which the **DIV** class and id varies and bit complicate to mention each and every tag and one common thing in all sites that in every page **MAIN** tags holds the actual content .

Thank you in Advance.

Updated: File changes in Repo

Comment: please provide a URL so that we are able to reproduce the problem, thanks

Comment: Hi Juien, I cannot post the website name for security reasons at this moment I can share the webpage source code [page1](https://github.com/an-snatcher/Sites/blob/master/page1.html) and [page2](https://github.com/an-snatcher/Sites/blob/master/page2.html).

Answer (score 0):

The files you posted have invalid elements:

```
<main rolle="main class>
```

and

```
<main role="main class="mobile-menu-fixed">
```

You can't expect the pattern to match if the attribute name is misspelled and/or double quotes are missing.

Comment: Hi Julien, my Bad that was a typo from my end. I updated the file in my repo the main content  first page starts from  **<main role=“main”>** and in second page  **<main role=“main” class=“mobile-menu-fixed”>**  and when I noticed few other  pages it just defined as **<main role=“main”>**  with out any class.

Comment: your 2nd file still has a dodgy main element but when fixing it can be extracted fine using MAIN[role="main"]. Same for the first document. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Is it required to specify the class names if exists or just **MAIN** tag is fine for text extraction?

Comment: http://stormcrawler.net/docs/api/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/parse/TextExtractor.html